# Geometry nodes: Instance on points node not working with image texture node

Tags: geometry-nodes, image, instances

I am trying to scatter objects on a plane with an image texture (logo). This works when only distributing points:

[image: Points distributed on a plane with a logo image]

The problem is that when i try to instance an object, the points disappear and nothing happens:

[image: points disappearing after adding instance on points node]

I am also not sure why the points are not aligned with the image texture but that's not my main concern right now.

Comment: looks like you still delete points instead of instances (in delete geometry). so either move the delete geometry BEFORE the instance on points....or change delete geometry to instance (but i am not totally sure that this works since i couldn't check it out because you didn't provide a blend file)

Comment: just one hint: you shouldn't write:"not working" instead you should write : what did i do wrong? because it sounds like you think it is a bug....which i don't believe

Comment: @Chris thank you, it worked :)

Comment: Hi, @Chris, can you pop in a quick answer, so we can mark this solved? Or.. if jebanik doesn't mind, we can close it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you delete points instead of instances, you can either move your delete geometry node before the instance on points node...

or...

change the delete geometry to "instance"